# Cuts in Graph Theory

Tags: graph

Generally, a cut is defined as a subset of a graph. However, I read in some places that all nodes in a cut must be connected. In this case, all subsets cannot becomes cut.

```
1----2
 \   |\  
  \  | \ 
   \ |  \
    \|   \
4----3    \
|__________5
```

In this case, is the set {3, 4, 5} a cut or not ? (the nodes 4 and 5 are not connected)

Comment: Subset does not seem to be right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)

Comment: Where did you read that all nodes in a cut must be connected?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [Reinhard Diestel's graduate textbook on Graph Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662536216), the definition of a "cut" is very simple:

> If {V1, V2} is a partition of V, the set E(V1, V2) of all the edges of
>   G *crossing* this partition is called a *cut*.

*NOTE: A "partition" of a set S is a set of disjoint subsets of S that completely cover S.*

Therefore, a "cut" is a set of edges, as described above, NOT a set of vertices. Furthermore, there is no requirement that either V1 or V2 be a connected subgraph.

Comment: There is definition in the book "Introduction to Algorithms" ,which is one of MIT publications. the definition In page 626 of that book says that a cut (S, V-S) of an undirected graph G = (V, E) is a partition of V. I think that cut is a vertex subset, since V is set of all vertices in the graph.